# existence of solutions to a second-order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering whether the equation 
\begin{equation}
f''-f^{1/3}=0,
\end{equation}
has a positive solution on the entire $\mathbb{R}$? or in general how do we prove the existence of solutions to a nonlinear ODE? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think if we rearrange the equation to get $f''=f^{\frac {1}{3}}$ then I think for a nonlinear ode of the form $f''=g ( t, f,f ')$ has a solution on the interval $[a, b]$ if $g $ is Lipschitz continuous on $[a, b]$

So the end result would be you need to find where $g=f^{\frac { 1 } {3}}$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: but $f$ is the solution, is there any method to show $f^{1/3}$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: You treat $f $ as a variable of $g $ and show that $g $ it Lipschitz

Comment: unfortunately $g(x)=x^{1/3}$ is not Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}$, it is Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}\[-\delta, \delta]$ though.

Comment: Then that would be a good candidate for an interval of existence.

Comment: but I need a solution on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ ...

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: Could you show me the reference for the statement in your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Page 6 (and onwards)      of this: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=dfA5U62NLoPKhAee3YDoBw&url=https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~temple/MAT22C/!!Lectures/3-ExistenceThmsOde-22C-S12.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHgkkDUsjbNsyHa8hzESAvmkGyFWg&sig2=jis5HUwQGcBTF9HIyZte0g

Comment: by the way, how could I make sure the solution is positive?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much you could do besides tailoring initial conditions, to find the best results, but I hope I have answered your question?